# CSS Grid dynamic size when hiding columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I want a certain item to take up the remaining space even when other item's are removed.

So currently I have two column items, one menu on the left and content on the right.

Currently my grid setup is like:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid: 1fr / 1fr 4fr;
}
```

The menu takes up the 1fr on the left and the content takes up the remaining 4fr. However the menu has a Javascript hide toggle function, so when I hide the menu the content becomes 1fr and 4fr is empty.

How do I make the content take up all the remaining space after the menu is hidden? I can do I with Javascript but is there a way with pure CSS Grid?

Answer (score 0):

If the toggle button is an input checkbox, you can use `#menu-toggle:checked .grid {}` to specify new rules.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

All I had to do was:

```css
grid: 1fr / auto auto;
```